# Conceptual issues in AR model

Tags: matlab

I have some basic questions regarding multivariate model. In the [ARFIT](http://www.clidyn.ethz.ch/arfit/index.html) toolbox, the demo file ardem.m shows the working of a 2nd order bivariate (v1,v2) AR model. The coefficient matrices

```
A1 = [ 0.4   1.2;   0.3   0.7 ]
A2 = [ 0.35 -0.3;  -0.4  -0.5 ]
```

are concatenated into

```
A = [ A1 A2 ]
```

Then a transpose of A is taken. So the result is a 2*4 matrix.

My question is that there should be only 4 coefficients viz. 2 for v1 variable and 2 for v2 variable but why are there 8 coefficients? If the equation format is

```
v(k,:) = a11*v1(k-1)+a12*v1(k-2) + a21*v2(k-1)+ a22*v2(k-2)
```

where `a11 = 0.4`, `a12=1.2`, `a21=0.3` and `a22=0.7`.

I think I am missing somewhere in understanding. Can somebody please explain what is the correct representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrices `A1` and `A2` contain transfer coefficients that describe the contribution of states at times `k-1` and `k-2`, respectively, to the state at time `k`. Since this is a bivariate process, we are following two variables which can influence each other, and both `A1` and `A2` are 2 x 2. Writing `v1 = v(k,1)` and `v2 = v(k,2)`:

```
v1(k) = A1(1,1)*v1(k-1) + A1(1,2)*v2(k-1) + A2(1,1)*v1(k-2) + A2(1,2)*v2(k-2)
```

and similarly for v2(k). Then collectively `A1` and `A2` contain 8 elements. If the two processes were independent then `A1` and `A2` would be diagonal and would collectively contain only 4 nonzero elements.

By the way this is not really a Matlab question so I don't think this is the right forum for this question.

Comment: I am not so familiar with Matlab's functions but presumably you can scale the AR model to include more than 2 processes. I would read the documentation since there may be limits on the size of the process for which solutions are considered stable.

Comment: You should pay attention to the sign of course, especially when using the coefficients generated by the AR model, but it is still largely a matter of convention how you write the original equations.